# Displaying RecyclerView into fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got methods:

```
private void initImageBitmaps() {
        mImageUrls.add("imageUrl");
        mNames.add("abcd");
        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    }
```

Which add images to my recyclerview. 
If it was in activity I would call `initImageBitmaps()` inside OnCreate. Unfortunately I have to use it in fragment and the question is: how to implement these methods to class which extends Fragment? Of course everything will be displayed into RecyclerView with recycler_view id in xml.

EDIT:
My Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(WallpapersFragment context, ArrayList<String> imageNames, ArrayList<String> images ) {
        mImageNames = imageNames;
        mImages = images;
        mContext = context;
        //Rquired is android.content.context and found is WallpapersFragment from my project
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.imageName.setText(mImageNames.get(position));

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mImages.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("image_name", mImageNames.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView imageName;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles only when I comment `mContext = context;` in adapter. Then the error is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a  Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).

Answer (score 0):

There is an onCreate() method in the Fragment class, but that method is different from activity's onCreate().

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}

    @Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            initRecyclerView();
    }
```

}

Read more about fragments here: [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: I tried to use this but I have an error that cannot resolve method findViewById

Answer (score 0):

`initRecyclerView(view)`;

And then:

```
 recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
```

Comment: Do this after @Andras Sanislo answer

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View view=   inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    initImageBitmaps(view);
  return view;
}


private void initImageBitmaps(View view) {
    mImageUrls.add("imageUrl");
    mNames.add("abcd");
    initRecyclerView(View view);
}

 private void initRecyclerView(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view); // init recyclerview
      GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);// declare layoutmanager
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); // set layoutmanager
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mNames, mImageUrls); // init adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); // set adapter in recyclerveiw
}
```

**EDIT**
 Replace *WallpapersFragment* with *Context* in adapter

```
 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageNames, ArrayList<String> images ) {
        mImageNames = imageNames;
        mImages = images;
        mContext = context;
        //Rquired is android.content.context and found is WallpapersFragment from my project
    }
```

Comment: In last line I have an error here: (this, 2) and I see that GridLayoutManager cannod be applied to my fragment

Comment: ok...then uncomment recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: and comment 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

Comment: the sam problem with LinearLayoutManager

Comment: if you use Gridlayout manager you need to declare 
new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2); because "this" is not valid in fragment

Comment: replace "this" to "getActivity()"

Comment: what is error now ?? edit answer...write what is error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a  Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed) This is from logcat

Comment: ok...try replace "getActivity" to "getContext()" and try again

Comment: or replace your initRecyclerview method with this..

private void initRecyclerView(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mNames, mImageUrls);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

Comment: same problem now

Comment: maybe you do mistake to set layout manager ...maybe you need to setLayoutManager before recyclerView.setadapter

Comment: Nothing works. Please give me solution and I'll test it in few hours

Comment: Unfortunately now there is no any error but app stops when I open this fragment

Comment: debug your fragment and adapter code and show what is problem

Comment: I guess that issue is in my adapte. I edited my post. Let's check it,

Comment: can you please add error what is displaly in logcat ? and also add full adapter code

Comment: are you use (in fragment )
 RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
OR
 RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mNames, mImageUrls);  ????

Comment: i edit my answer..show edit part and also show what you use "this" or "getContext()" in fragment

Comment: When I edited the code and replaced with one from edit I had to replace "this" to getContext() in Fragment and now app doesn't boot - it crash immediately. I really don't know what to do. Would you agree to share whole project and you would check yourself?

Comment: no..you have to search Recyclerview demo from google and understand it  or find some Recyclerview implementation tutorial

Comment: maybe this example can be help 1) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your recycler view in following lifecycle callback:

```
onViewCreated()
```

and can also populate data method here like

> initRecyclerView()
>
> initImageBitmaps()

and for data refresh you can call notifyDatasetChanged() on adapter.